# Is there any "serverless" / global database hosting?

Tags: database, database-design, key-value, p2p

I am bulling a little python + GTK app.

I need a way where I can store some index data on a server.

First I looked at RedHat´s OpenShift as the server rest-backend (python + flask + mysql)

But now I am thinking is there a way to just put some data into the "cloud".

I know the cloud just I a buzz word for other peoples computers / servers.

But something like the bitcoin where you just push some key/val data then any node in the network gets the data after some time.

Apache Cassandra look like can do some thing like this.

But I don't want to host anything.

Some thing like this.

```
$ datacloud <openid> <password> <databucket>
$ datacloud add <key> <jsondata / val>
$ datacloud get <key>
$ <jsondata>
```

Or in python.

```
import datacloud as dc
import json

def main():
    dc.connect("<myopenid.provider.org>", "<password>", "<databucket>")

    ds.add("key", json.dumps({"hello":"world"}))

    for data in dc:
      print data  

    print dc.get("<key>")
    --> { "hello": "world"}
```

Or better just with jQuery.

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script href="pathto/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>ServerLess / local site</title>
    <script>
    $(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url: "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5dee65101db281ac9c46344cd6b175cdcad53426",
          data: {
             "openid": "<openid.myopenidprovier.org>",
             "password": "<12345>",
             "bucket": "<databucket>"
          } 
       }).done(function(keys){
            for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++)
                $('#news').append('<h3>'+key[i]+'</h3>');
       });
    });
    </script
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>News with no server</h1>
      <div id="news"></div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I am looking for an p2p global key/val store.

... an freenet like data global key/val cache or store..

**Update**: the idea base on @SLaks comments.

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script href="pathto/jquery.js"></script>
    <title>ServerLess / local site</title>
    <script>
    $(function(){
       $.ajax({
          url: "magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5dee65101db281ac9c46344cd6b175cdcad53426",
          data: {
             "pubkey": "<id_rsa.pub>",
             "bucket": "<databucket>"
          } 
       }).done(function(keys){
            for(var i=0; i < keys.length; i++)
                $('#news').append('<h3>'+key[i]+'</h3>');
       });
    });
    </script
   </head>
   <body>
  <h1>News with no server</h1>
  <div id="news"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Use ssh-keygen -t rsa

So only the admin can add data.

Comment: Passing your password to every client in JS sounds like a horrible idea.  If you want any kind of access control or data protection, you don't actually want to do that.

Comment: Look at hosted data platforms like Azure Mobile Services.

Answer (score 0):

Um, no. A P2P network without commercial interest will not host your database for free.

So, you really just need a minimal database storage? You can buy that from multiple places. Look at the overly known Amazon AWS stuff. I'm sure you can rent database VM instances, too, or directly use the Amazon relational database service. I think for your "nearly no users, nearly no data" thing, a simple VM with a secure preconfigured database that you can only connect to through SSH or some VPN will probably be the most cost-effective solution.

However, it sounds like you'd quickly whip up a webservice, which would allow you to authenticate simple HTTPS clients securely, and then ask for / store the data of your application through that. That way, you can also solve the dilemma of not sharing your credentials with others.

Comment: The idea is not to use or be dependent on all the big data centers. Many frontend developer don´t care abort end backend. p2p project like https://github.com/freenet/pyFreenet do thing like this for free. But the implementation look like, it has to much overhead.

Comment: Seriously, what's wrong with your perception is that although you need an easy central storage you'll get away easier by not having a central storage. Having a small database run somewhere really isn't complicated, or big-datacentry or anything. Also, you'd generally *prefer*, for redundancy reasons, your data to be maintained by someone doing it on a large scale. Just saying.

Comment: and freenet will *not* give you a distributed key value database with coherent update possibilities. That's really a misunderstanding of how things work.

Comment: Yep I know it is not easier to do this. Ok freenet is not the way to go. I fund an db project doing thing more like this Prophet at http://syncwith.us/

Comment: that seems pretty dead. and still, what you want is central storage. none of your requirements make sense.

Comment: peer2peer updatable key/value storage is extremely hard to do right – there's a reason why the entire Bitcoin blockchain can do a maximum of a couple transfers per second. Really. A distributed database without central authority is NOT something you want to use in a simple web application. It's hard, and the risks are substatntial, and the computational and bandwidth overhead is **very** bad.

Comment: Yes it look like is a to big of a task to do. I will do the standard way. Thanks for the reply :)